# Bash: Variable contains executable path -> Convert to string

Tags: string, bash, variables, cut, esxi

I have this problem and not found a sufficient solutionyet, maybe you guys can help me.

I need to do this:

```
find -name some.log
```

It will give a lot hits back. So now I would like to go through it with a "for" like this:

```
    for a in $(find -name vmware.log)
    do
      XXXXXXX
    done
```

After that, I would like to cut the path in variable $a. Lets assume, $a has the following content:

```
./this/is/a/path/some.log
```

I'll cut this variable with

```
cut -d/ -f2 $a
```

The finished code is like this:

```
for a in $(find -name vmware.log)
do
  cutpath=cut -d/ -f2 $a
done
```

When I do this, the bash uses the content of $a as a system path and not as a string. So "cut" tries to access the file directly, but it should only cut the string path in $a.The error I get on VMware ESXi is:

```
-sh: ./this/is/a/path/some.log: Device or resource busy
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, looping through the output of `find` with `for` is discouraged, since it's not going to work for filenames containing spaces or glob metacharacters (such as `*`).

This achieves what you want, using the `-exec` switch. The name of the file `{}` is passed to the script as `$0`.

```
find -name 'vmware.log' -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" | cut -d/ -f2' {} \;
# or with bash
find -name 'vmware.log' -exec bash -c 'cut -d/ -f2 <<<"$0"' {} \;
```

It looks like you want to use cut on the filename, rather than the file's contents, so you need to pass the name to cut on standard input, not as an argument. This can be done using a pipe `|` or using Bash's `<<<` herestring syntax.

Comment: Tried :) But with no luck. Here the output: "find: -exec requires an argument"
This I have executed: "find -name 'vmware.log' -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" | cut -d/ -f2' {} \"

Comment: @Sperk rather than pasting output into a comment, please update your question to show us some example paths that would be matched by `find` and the desired output.

Comment: @Sperk you didn't copy the syntax correctly if you didn't include the `\;` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I indeed have copied it wrong. It works like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -2):

You should try to use something like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1="$1"
VAR2="$2"

MOREF='sudo run command against $VAR1 | grep name | cut -c7-'

echo $MOREF
```

Using tickquotes will execute the command and store it in the variable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer. I have tried to play around with your solution with no luck. Can you explain it a little different?

Comment: I suggest to use `MOREF=$(...)`.

Comment: The code in this answer is incorrect and appears to be directly copied from the internet https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash.html